# Make name of list uploaded to Sharepoint from Excel adjustable

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I have working code to upload an Excel Table to SharePoint, but I can only upload it once with the same name.

```
Sub UploadToSharepoint()

Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Publish Array( _
    "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointsite", "SharepointList2"), _
    False

End Sub
```

The name of the List being: `SharepointList2` right now.

Is there a way to make this name either adjustable with User Input (UserForm) or to simply make it today's date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Publish Array( _
"https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointsite", format(date,"yyyy-mm-dd")), _
False
```

Comment: IT'S ALIVE! Thank you so much! Kinda embarrassed that I couldn't find that myself.

Comment: You could also go down the user defined route, but you then have to apply text validation etc. to prevent non-compatible characters being used.

Comment: If you want to include the time: `format(now,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss")` - remove the `:ss` if it's too much.